# Show the array of images in an imageview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have a view controller which loads an array of images when instantiated. I have a slider used to select which image to show. Now I want to show a custom slider with preview of each images that the user could tap. I have tried some code but whenever i tap the image in the slider it only shows first image in an image view from the array that are coming from server and it does not show the other images from the array. The code i tried is this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"property_images"];
NSLog(@"GGG %@",arrayOfImages);

self.imagesData=[[NSArray alloc]init];
self.imagesData = arrayOfImages;
NSLog(@"Image Array is %@",_imagesData);

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    // imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandImage:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.view.tag = i;
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group); 
    }];

    _fullImage.hidden=NO;
    _fullView.hidden=NO;
}
```

the expand method is this,

```
 -(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{
   //  _fullImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:recogniser.view.tag]];

    [_fullImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:recogniser.view.tag]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch.png"]];
    NSLog(@"RRR %@",self.imagesData);
    NSLog(@"TTT %ld",recogniser.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864821/display-array-of-images-in-uiimageview

Comment: its a slider i want to show only one image on which i tap in slider. @R.Mohan

Comment: move this line `dispatch_group_enter(group);` in above of this `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake`

Comment: ok, i understand it now, do you check that recogniser tag is coming correct ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to store ```UIImage``` array in ```NSUserDefaults```? I'm pretty sure storing data in general is discouraged. You are only supposed to store simple binary settings or strings in ```NSUserDefaults```, not image data. Store your images in ```NSPicturesDirectory``` instead.

Comment: else try move your `UITapGestureRecognizer *tap` to inside the block of `sd_setImageWithURL`

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions.** If you have an answer, post it as an answer. If additional information needs to be added, then [edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set tag on `imageView.tag` instead of `tap.view.tag`.

You are setting `tap.view.tag` when `tap.view` contains `nil` value.

Comment: How to do that. @Lal Krishna